# UWP doesn't find any BLE devices using StartScanningForDevicesAsync (Plugin.BLE for Xamarin)

Tags: android, xamarin, uwp, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to find BLE devices using Xamarin Plugin.BLE
The code is

```
adapter.DeviceDiscovered += (s, a) => deviceList.Add(a.Device);
adapter.ScanTimeout = 30000;
await adapter.StartScanningForDevicesAsync();
```

UWP finds 0 devices.
At the same time Bluetooth LE Explorer (a utility from Microsoft) finds and my device, and a dozen of others.
What could be the problem? Windows 10, .NET v4.8, Plugin.BLE v2.2.0-pre, Xamarin.Forms 5.0
I prefer to use Xamarin because I want my code to be cross platform - Windows and Android

Nico's comment solved it. However I have another question, closely related. Now UWP finds service and updates characteristic suceesfully. However on Android simulator that I run from Visual Studio, the same code doesn't find anything.
Is there something I am missing again?
I have these lines in AndroidManifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

    <!--this is necessary for Android v6+ to get the device name and address-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

TIA

Comment: Have you enable UWP Bluetooth capability ?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT You were right! I forgot. Thank you!

Comment: Good, May Convert it as answer for this problem?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Definitely! Maybe you have any ideas on the update - second part of the question too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> UWP doesn't find any BLE devices using StartScanningForDevicesAsync (Plugin.BLE for Xamarin)

Please check if you have added Bluetooth capability for UWP platform, double click `Package.appxmainfest` file -> find Capabilities -> enable Bluetooth capablity.

> However on Android simulator that I run from Visual Studio, the same code doesn't find anything.

I'm afraid you can't enable bluetooth device for Android simulator, please refer this document [limitations](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator#limitations), please test the app with physical device.

Answer (score 0):

> UWP doesn't find any BLE devices using StartScanningForDevicesAsync (Plugin.BLE for Xamarin)

Please refer this [link](https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le/issues/362), `Plugin.BLE` for UWP is TBA state, and it is not support UWP yet. If you do want to use this plugin please refer MenaceSan's comment.

*You dont use the whole branch . just pull the UWP project out of it.
Just copy the UWP project (Plugin.BLE.UWP) and include it as a referenced project (Not using NuGet)*